# How I get ajax and assign data before view render

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I try put the ajax.get in created function but i still can't get the ap_name value

vue.js

```
created: function () {
        ajax.get('/envs').then(function (res) {
            this.apName = res.AP_NAME;
            console.log(this.apName);
        });
 },
```

html

```
 <a :href="`${apName}/home`"</a>
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an arrow function so that `this` isn't obscured by the context of the passed function:

```js
created: function () {
        ajax.get('/envs').then((res) => {
            this.apName = res.AP_NAME;
            console.log(this.apName);
        });
 },
```

And you may need to change this line to:

```js
this.apName = res.data.AP_NAME;
```